# Why are my images being distorted in my table?

Tags: html, css

Here is a link to the page that is having issue: http://sites.udel.edu/materials-characterization/ .

As you can see, the images in the 1-row, 6-column table are being wildly distorted. I'm terrible with coding tables and their css and can't seem to work it so that the images will show as 120px by 120px. I'm sure it's something simple and obvious, but I just haven't been able to get it right. I've tried setting these settings in my css:

```
td {
  padding:0px;
  width:16.6%;
  margin:0px;}
```

To no avail.

This is the table's html:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img style="height: 120px;" src="http://imageshack.com/a/img661/7633/1iiqa5.png" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img style="height: 120px;" src="http://imageshack.com/a/img905/7443/rsWUcI.png" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img style="height: 120px;" src="http://imageshack.com/a/img537/6786/ISbtBn.png" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img style="height: 120px;" src="http://imageshack.com/a/img912/2283/wjNYwR.png" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img style="height: 120px;" src="http://imageshack.com/a/img673/7112/0wOLLR.png" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img style="height: 120px;width:120px;" src="http://imageshack.com/a/img661/8118/qKGYlR.png" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thank you in advance for any advice you can give me!

Comment: You gave the `td`s a width of 16.6%, that's why.
http://i.imgur.com/HfzjqYw.png

Comment: Thank you all for the speedy and helpful responses! Now the padding/margins are too wide, but I think I can take it from here!

Answer (score 3):

Remove `#content img{max-width:100%}`.  You are specifying a height for all the images which are skewing the image ratios.

Comment: Yep, you will have to choose if you use `width` or `height`. Not both at the same time if you want to keep the image ratio.

Answer (score 0):

I'd switch to a responsive approach. Remove the **style** attribute on your  tags and add this to the css:

```
td img {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   }
```

This way, the images might get scaled but shouldn't be distorted.

Answer (score 0):

You set `padding: 6px 24px;` on line 743 in style.css which override `padding: 0;` declared in the question.